# Cómo puedo solucionar la lectura a traves de modulos en python y tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz

soy nuevo programando en python y tambien en general. Estoy utilizando customtkinter para una interfaz que usaré en mi trabajo. En la ventana principal, tengo una serie de widgets que inican el modelo de equipo que estoy utilizando para las pruebas.

```
self.wHipotmodelL = CTkLabel(wRightFrame, text=("Modelo Hipot:"), font=("roboto", 25, "bold"), justify="center", text_color="black", fg_color="transparent")
    self.wHipotmodelL.place(x=50, y=240)
    self.wHipotmodelLE = CTkEntry(wRightFrame, width=120, height=30, font=("Roboto", 25), justify = "center")
    self.wHipotmodelLE.insert(0, cModel)
    self.wHipotmodelLE.configure(fg_color="white", text_color="black", border_color = cBorder, border_width = 3, state = "disabled")
    self.wHipotmodelLE.place(x=250, y=240)
```

En el entry inserto la variable global `cModel = cf.get_model_hipot()` anteriormente declarada.

La función `get_model_hipot()` esta en otro módulo que anteriormente importe con `import Modules.config as cf` en el modulo de donde mando a llamar la función.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

vConfigFile = "././Config/config.ini"

config = ConfigParser()
config.read(vConfigFile)

#GET
def get_model_hipot(): return config["GENERAL"]["HIPOT"]

#PUT
def put_model_hipot(vModel):
    config["GENERAL"]["HIPOT"] = vModel
    with open(vConfigFile, "w") as file:
    config.write(file)
```

La función realiza una lectura del siguiente archivo ".ini".

```
[GENERAL]
hipot = 7850
logs = C:\HipotReports
models = ././Models
port = COM1
workstation = XXXXX  XXXXX  XXX
```

Hasta ahí basicamente es la lectura del modelo de equipo que quiero actualizar, sin embargo, tengo una ventana emergente que abro llamando la función desde un boton en la pagina principal.

```
#Config Window
def config(self):

    #Config Window
    self.wConfig = CTkToplevel()
    self.wConfig.geometry(f"{830}x{780}+{10}+{30}")
    self.wConfig.title("Configuración")
    self.wConfig.resizable(0,0)
    self.wConfig.attributes("-topmost", True)

    #Config Frame
    wConfigframe = CTkFrame(self.wConfig, width = 245, height = 460)
    wConfigframe.pack(fill = "both", expand=True, padx=15, pady=15)

    #Hipot config
    self.wHipotConfigLabel = CTkLabel(wConfigframe, text="Configuración del Hipot", font=("roboto", 20, "bold"), text_color="black")
    self.wHipotConfigLabel.place(x=80, y=20)
    
    self.wHipotOpMenu = CTkOptionMenu(wConfigframe, height = 30, width = 120, fg_color = "white", font = ("Roboto", 15), text_color = "black", button_hover_color = cOk, button_color = "white", values = ("7850", "7650", "7550"), dynamic_resizing = False)
    self.wHipotOpMenu.set(cf.get_model_hipot())
    self.wHipotOpMenu.place(x=50, y=110)
    self.wHipotOpLabel = CTkLabel(wConfigframe, text="Modelo de HIPOT", font=("roboto", 15), text_color="black")
    self.wHipotOpLabel.place(x=55 , y=70)
    self.wHipotSaveButton = CTkButton(wConfigframe, text="Guardar", command=self.save_hipot_model, font=("Roboto", 15, "bold"), text_color = "white", fg_color=cOk, border_color = cBorder, border_width = 3, width = 100, height = 40)
    self.wHipotSaveButton.place(x=245, y=100)
    self.wConfig.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.hide_settings)
```

En esta ventana tiene una lista en la que modifico el modelo del equipo y un boton que sirve para escribir ese dato en el archivo ".ini" con la siguiente función `self.save_hipot_model` y que hace lo siguiente:

```
def save_hipot_model(self):
    cf.put_model_hipot(self.wHipotOpMenu.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Configuración guardada exitosamente")
```

En este apartado se manda llamar a la función `cf.put_model_hipot` del siguiente móulo:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

vConfigFile = "././Config/config.ini"

config = ConfigParser()
config.read(vConfigFile)

#GET
def get_model_hipot(): return config["GENERAL"]["HIPOT"]

#PUT
def put_model_hipot(vModel):
    config["GENERAL"]["HIPOT"] = vModel
    with open(vConfigFile, "w") as file:
    config.write(file)
```

Hasta aqui todo el proceso de lectura y escritura de este dato. El problema viene cuando agrego la función de actualizar el dato en la pagina principal cuando la ventana de configuración se cierra,`self.wConfig.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.hide_settings)`

```
def hide_settings(self):
    self.wConfig.withdraw()
    self.master.attributes("-disabled", False)
    self.wHipotmodelLE.configure(state="normal")
    self.wHipotmodelLE.delete(0,"end")
    self.wHipotmodelLE.insert(0, cModel)
    self.wHipotmodelLE.configure(state="disabled")
```

El modelo del equipo de prueba se sobrescribe en el archivo ".ini" pero la lectura toma el dato anterior. Basicamente no lee el dato actual y se queda con el anterior hasta que reinicie el programa. Tambien he intentado imprimiendo la variable `cModel` en la terminal despues de la escritura, pero sigue pasando lo mismo.

No se si el diagrama de flujo esta mal, en que parte estoy haciendo algo mal o si se puede hacer de otra forma, pero espero entiendan el problema y que alguien pueda ayudarme a solucionarlo o a encontrar información útil.

La verdad he sido precavido al publicar esto por temas de privacidad de la empresa y ademas por no tener el conocimiento ni experiencia necesaria para saber que puede ser perjudicial o no.

Es de mis primeras veces publicuando alguna pregunta y programando en general, asi que acepto criticas y comentarios para mejorar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En principio, en `hide_settings` deberias volver a obtener el dato: `self.wHipotmodelLE.insert(0, cf.get_model_hipot())`